# dax calculate measure for powerBi and return one value with group

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

I am really new on PowerBi, and i am facing a problem with DAX.

I want to have for powerBi a measure and this measure in calculated on SSAS tabular model.

the measure will compute the number of best bid by product and by client `Count(max(bid)) by product and by client`, and taking under account only the last bid by product

I created a variable (bestBidTable) with DAX that is doing the work, that returns 3 columns 'client', 'product', 'best_bid', here are a data sample of var bestBidTable :

| client | product | best_bid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 1 | B | 20 |
| 1 | C | 30 |
| 2 | D | 30 |
| 2 | E | 40 |
| 2 | F | 55 |
| 3 | G | 60 |
| 3 | H | 70 |

Now what I want to do, is to have count(product) by client , in SQL it will be `select count(product) from bestBidTable group by client` , But because i needed as a measure for powerBi I shouldn't use summarize function it returns multiple columns.
how to do this :)

here is the code :

`    VAR saleFiltered =
SUMMARIZE (
CALCULATETABLE(
'Sale Events',
FILTER ( 'Sale Events', 'Sale Events'[Sale Type] == "Bid"),
FILTER ( 'Sales', 'Sales'[State] == "Closed")
) ,
'product'[id],
'Contacts'[Code client],
"maxprice", MAX ( 'Sale Events'[Sale Event Price (?)])
)

```
VAR BestBidTable =  
 SUMMARIZE (  
  FILTER (  
   ADDCOLUMNS(  
    saleFiltered,   
    "rn",  
    ROWNUMBER(  
    saleFiltered,  
    ORDERBY([maxprice], desc),  
    PARTITIONBY('product'[id])  
    )  
   ),  
   [rn] = 1  
  ),  
 'Contacts'[Code client], 'product'[id] , [maxprice] 
 )  
 
 
 RETURN  
SUMMARIZE (
    BestBidTable,
    'Contacts'[Code client],
    "numberVbestBid", COUNT ( 'product'[id] )
)
```

`

this code is giving the correct result in SSAS, but unfortunately i can't use it in PowerBi as measure because it is returning 2 values.

Maybe i should link the codeClient from numberVbestBid with an object that i have in the model called client, in this way when the user select client object with the measure he will have the group by automatically, but i have no clue if it is that the  solution

Thank you

Comment: You have not upvoted or marked as solved any of your previous questions.

Comment: no, how you do the matrix. here is the code ? i update my question

Comment: SUMMARIZE returns a table. it's working. What were you trying to return? Just the count?

Comment: I replaced summarize with Count (the following code),    
`   
    RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
    COUNT('product'[id]), BestBidTable 
    )
`

now it is returning one value (which is good), 
But in powerBi when i select this new measure and the object  [Code client] , it doesnt give the same result as SUMMARIZE, 
maybe there is a need to link the object (code client) from the temporary table with the base table 'Contacts'[Code client] ??